# SQL CASE in GROUP BY

Tags: postgresql, group-by, case, exists, conditional-aggregation

I have a query that is meant to get the count of each reaction on a comment and whether the user is one of the people who made that reaction. However, my case statement returns includesMe:1 for EVERY reaction when the user has made at least one reaction on the comment.

Eg, if the user only reacted to , my query returns that they reacted to every reaction:

[image]

```
SELECT count(*) as "numReacts", 
       reaction, 
       case when exists(
            select *
            from "CommentReaction" as i
            where i."userId" = 'b8b660c9-c416-42b6-9142-19112a9ff811' 
              and i."commentId" = 'c142787b-4422-4128-8357-58d36c177307' 
              and i.reaction = reaction
            ) 
            then 1
            else 0
       end as "includesMe" 
FROM "CommentReaction" 
WHERE "commentId" = 'c142787b-4422-4128-8357-58d36c177307' 
GROUP BY reaction;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition:

```
and i.reaction = reaction
```

is evaluated as `TRUE` because the unqualified column `reaction` is considered to be the column of the inner subquery's table.
You could alias the outer table, for example

```
FROM "CommentReaction" AS t
```

and change to

```
and i.reaction = t.reaction
```

but I believe that you can solve your problem with a simpler query if you use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "numReacts", 
       reaction, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN "userId" = 'b8b660c9-c416-42b6-9142-19112a9ff811' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "includesMe" 
FROM "CommentReaction" 
WHERE "commentId" = 'c142787b-4422-4128-8357-58d36c177307' 
GROUP BY reaction;
```

or:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "numReacts", 
       reaction, 
       MAX(("userId" = 'b8b660c9-c416-42b6-9142-19112a9ff811')::int) AS "includesMe" 
FROM "CommentReaction" 
WHERE "commentId" = 'c142787b-4422-4128-8357-58d36c177307' 
GROUP BY reaction;
```

Comment: Thank you! The MAX in your last code example needs another set of parentheses; right now it is trying to get the MAX of a boolean

Comment: @Flo you are right, the conversion to int must be inside MAX().

Answer (score 0):

the database interprets reaction as belonging  to the alias i.

you need to use the original name (or in my case the alias c) to get te rigt column

```
SELECT 
          count(*) as "numReacts", 
          reaction, 
          case
                when exists (
                    select *
                    from "CommentReaction" as i
                    where i."userId" = 'b8b660c9-c416-42b6-9142-19112a9ff811' and i."commentId" = 'c142787b-4422-4128-8357-58d36c177307' and i.reaction = c.reaction
                ) then 1
                else 0
            end as "includesMe" 
        FROM "CommentReaction" as c WHERE "commentId" = 'c142787b-4422-4128-8357-58d36c177307' GROUP BY reaction;
```